# Python - how to run the gtk.main() which does not block my whole application and allow me to do multi-tasking?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

I have this Python skeleton, where main.py is fine and server.py is fine. But the moment chat() is launched i see the GUI, but the moment `gtk.main()` was executed it does not allow any activity under server.py module nor in chat.py itself.

How can i have the chat.py flexible so that it does not interupt other class and run all like multi-task?

Note: os.system('/var/tmp/chat.py') when i execute from server.py then i have no issue but i problem is i cant communicate in that way (so trying to avoid that method)

Any idea, why and how can i make chat.py work independently without causing my whole application to be blocked until chat.py is exit?

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from myglobal import bgcolors
from myglobal import parsePresets
from server import server
from chat import chat
t = server(58888)
t.start()
```

server.py

```
class server(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, port):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.port = port
    self.selfv = chat()
    self.selfv.run()

  def run(self):
    host = ''
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind((host, self.port))
    #s.setblocking(0) # non-blocking
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    serverFlag = True
    while serverFlag:
      try:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
      except socket.error:
        s.listen(1)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        continue

      if not data:
        s.listen(1)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
      else:
        line = data
        conn.send('ok')
        conn.close()
```

chat.py

```
class chat(object):

  def listener(self, sock, *args):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    gobject.io_add_watch(conn, gobject.IO_IN, self.handler)
    return True

  def handler(self, conn, *args):
    line = conn.recv(4096)
    if not len(line):
      return False
    else:
      return True

  def __init__(self):
    self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    self.window.set_size_request(800, 450)
    self.window.move(0,0)
    self.window.set_name("main window")
    self.window.connect("delete-event", gtk.main_quit)
    self.drawingarea = gtk.DrawingArea()
    self.window.add(self.drawingarea)

  def run(self):
    self.sock = socket.socket()
    self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.sock.bind(('', 58881))
    self.sock.listen(1)
    gobject.io_add_watch(self.sock, gobject.IO_IN, self.listener)
    self.window.show_all()
    self.window.set_keep_above(True)
    if(self.window.get_window().get_state() == gtk.gdk.WINDOW_STATE_MAXIMIZED):
      self.window.unmaximize()
    gtk.main()

  def quit(self):
    gtk.main_quit()


#if __name__=='__main__':
#    s=SelfView()
#    s.run()
    #gobject.MainLoop.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm missing too many things to test your code, so my answer will not be very confident.

Your constructor for the `server` object calls the `run` method of your `chat` object, which in turn calls `gtk.main()`.  This starts running GTK's event loop, and therefore nothing more will happen in this thread until the GUI is closed by the user.  Actually, the `start` method for your server thread does not have a chance of being executed.

I suppose you want to run `gtk.main()` on a different thread.  To suggest how to do this, I'm afraid I need more information about what you're trying to do.  Perhaps you need to make your `chat` object an instance of `threading.Thread`, too.

Comment: i made chat.py like you have mentioned but same. as soon as gtk.main() was executed it never allow other statement to work.

Comment: When you call `gtk.main()`, it will never return until the user quits the GUI.  This has to be done in a separate thread.  The call to `gtk.main()` will have to be in the `run` method of the separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Always run gui in the main thread. Start server in another thread before gui starts. Close the listener after gui quits.

Comment: i have also tried your suggestion but it did not worked, actually i have one protocol which open main window and second window , third window etc, when exit it close all window. So main application is the server.py in my case which decide to run any Gui or not.

Comment: Only run gtk.main() once in your program. If you just want to show the chat windows after the main gui is already there, just call show or its equivalent. Remember to call any gui related stuff in the main thread.